# Why are lines from my table visible to specific queries but not otherwise?

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, mariadb, synology, nas

I am setting up a database for my company. Among the reference tables it needed are a list of all the villages in a specific country (I don't want to specify where, but it's over 70k items). The database is saved to a local synology NAS, run through MariaDBS, and I'm managing it with phpMyAdmin.

After I got the entire list imported, a weird problem as come up: The last 70-200 (it varies each time I pull up phpmyadmin, and sometimes varies within a single session) items, listed alphabetically by name (not the primary key) won't appear in browse, even if I filter for it specifically by name or key. However, if I go to the sql query box for that table and query it by name, it works fine. For example

```
SELECT * FROM villages WHERE village_name = "something";
```

works exactly as expected. Likewise

```
SELECT * FROM villages WHERE village_name IS Not Null;
```

also pulls up the entire list from the initial import just fine.

Is this going to cause a problem, or is it just a quirk of my setup that, while inconvenient, won't actually impact any of the real work that comes later?

Normally in phpMyAdmin the browse tab for a table produces the same list as a query that would show the entire list. It does not.

Comment: They are rows, not lines. At any rate, are you certain the SQL client just isn't truncating the results and you need to scroll/page to see the remaining rows? And there is no "sorting" in tables. While it may look alphabetical, that's not necessarily the case unless you ORDER BY within a query.

Comment: if the import data has no cells that are empty and we wouldn't expect that the village name would be empty in any case, so that is nothing unusual about it

Comment: "the villages in a specific country" -- Where is the `AND country = 'foo'` in those queries?

Comment: Please provide the failing query and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.